# FragmentManager with old Activity reference (java.lang.IllegalStateException)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, fragmentmanager

I am developing an app using the v4-lib. Inside a FragmentActivity I have a FragmentPagerAdapter holding my Fragments. After sliding through all my Fragments I call Finish() on the Activity. Now it get's complicated: when restarting the app (not totally killed via the TaskManager) the screen remains white and the system says:

> 12-01 09:49:44.933  10161-10161/com.xxx.yyy W/System.err﹕ java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
>   12-01 09:49:44.933  10161-10161/com.xxx.yyy W/System.err﹕ at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1387)
>   12-01 09:49:44.933  10161-10161/com.xxx.yyy W/System.err﹕ at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:636)
>   12-01 09:49:44.933  10161-10161/com.xxx.yyy W/System.err﹕ at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:619)
>   12-01 09:49:44.933  10161-10161/com.xxx.yyy W/System.err﹕ at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:139)
>   12-01 09:49:44.933  10161-10161/com.xxx.yyy W/System.err﹕ at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(ViewPager.java:420)
>   12-01 09:49:44.933  10161-10161/com.xxx.yyy W/System.err﹕ at com.yyy.zzz_lib.ui.AbstractQuestionnaireActivity.setUpLayout(AbstractQuestionnaireActivity.java:78)
>   12-01 09:49:44.933  10161-10161/com.xxx.yyy W/System.err﹕ at com.yyy.zzz.QuestionnaireActivity.setContent(QuestionnaireActivity.java:58)
>   12-01 09:49:44.933  10161-10161/com.xxx.yyy W/System.err﹕ at com.yyy.zzz.QuestionnaireActivity.handleMessage(QuestionnaireActivity.java:100)
>   12-01 09:49:44.933  10161-10161/com.xxx.yyy W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>   12-01 09:49:44.933  10161-10161/com.xxx.yyy W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   12-01 09:49:44.933  10161-10161/com.xxx.yyy W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5586)
>   12-01 09:49:44.933  10161-10161/com.xxx.yyy W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   12-01 09:49:44.933  10161-10161/com.xxx.yyy W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   12-01 09:49:44.933  10161-10161/com.xxx.yyy W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
>   12-01 09:49:44.933  10161-10161/com.xxx.yyy W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
>   12-01 09:49:44.933  10161-10161/com.xxx.yyy W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

After debugging a bit I noticed that when I reopen the activity there is still the old reference to the last Activity on the FM, later when setting the Adapter on the ViewPager the Activity is null and the app crashes. When cleaning up the whole app through the TaskManager all goes again the right way once.
I tried several things: popping the whole back stack, holding a new reference to the FragmentManager, playing around with Fragment.retainInstanceState() and so on.. unfortunately nothing worked out. I see no possibility to get a clean instance of the FragmentManager. Can anybody help me with this issue?

**Update:** some code snippets:

```
public abstract class AbstractQuestionnaireActivity extends FragmentActivity {

  private QuestionnaireModel mQuestionnaireModel;

  private QuestionnaireViewPager mPager;
  private QuestionnairePagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

  public void setUpLayout(int layoutRoot) {

    try {
      FrameLayout root = (FrameLayout) findViewById(layoutRoot);

      //inflate questionnaire layout
      View questionnaire = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.elem_questionnaire, null);
      root.addView(questionnaire);

      mPagerAdapter = new QuestionnairePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
      mPager = (QuestionnaireViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
      mPager.setPagingEnabled(false);
      mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

      ...

    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
      throw new ClassCastException("Layout root must be a FrameLayout!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  ...

  public class QuestionnairePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public QuestionnairePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
      super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
      return mQuestionnaireModel.getQuestions().get(pos).createFragment(pos);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return mQuestionnaireModel.getQuestions().size();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the related code that you are referring to?